# Rails 5: select_tag options for select with gteq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, ransack

I am currently trying to display the :wine_type options with wine_type_gteq in my home view.

The problem I'm facing is that wine_type_gteq doesn't get accepted.

```
<div class="s003">
    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
      <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
     <%= select_tag :wine_type_gteq, [["Grauburgunder", "Grauburgunder"]], prompt: "Select..." %>
    </div>
        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Wein...", class: "form-control", id: "autolocation" %>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field third-wrap">
          <button class="btn-search">
            <%= submit_tag "Suchen", style: "color:white" %>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rails gives me an error and says can't convert array into string so I changed the line to:

```
<%= select_tag.to_s :wine_type_gteq, [["Grauburgunder", "Grauburgunder"]], prompt: "Select..." %>
```

Now it's converting the array into a string, but I'm still getting an ActionView error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem this line has:

```
<%= select_tag :wine_type_gteq, [["Grauburgunder", "Grauburgunder"]], prompt: "Select..." %>
```

is in options for your `select` tag. Please check [examples](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) how this helper can be used. An array of options is not accepted as the 2nd argument of `select_tag`. You could write options in raw HTML, but handier is to use `options_for_select` method, which generates these options in HTML format.

Also in the options list values and texts seem to be the same, so it can be simplified.

Correct tag is:

```
<%= select_tag :wine_type_gteq, options_for_select(["Grauburgunder"]), prompt: "Select..." %>
```

Comment: That's not the answer I was looking for. I am using ransack and arel, the problem is that I have dynamic options in the select_tag field.

Comment: I don’t understand the problem then. Your question is about a syntax error in the template, with static options.